# Site Layout doesn't render in any other page except default page in asp.net razor website

Tags: asp.net, razor

Site Layout doesn't render in any other page except default page in `asp.net` razor website in remote server

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: I was trying to redirect page using .cshtml extension which should not be used.

Just use

```
response.redirect(filename without extension(.cshtml))
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your _SiteLayout located?
Normally you would have to do something like:

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
```